# Brackets code editor doesn't let me close h1 class

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

I apologise in advance if I'm missing something very obvious. I'm just getting started on web development.

I'm using Brackets and I'm trying to apply a class to h1 using this code:

```
<h1 class="floatright">A Message from the Chief</h1>
```

The problem is, when I type the closing " in floatright, the rest of the code (basically the rest of the body) flags up in red. However, if I leave it as

```
 <h1 class="floatright><h1>A Message from the Chief</h1>
```

Brackets seems to think it's ok. I've attached two screenshots for more details. Am I missing something very obvious here?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NRofnAq.jpg]

And:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlRvQ.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing `"` in your `style` attribute on line 70.

A good clue there is to see where the red *starts*, then work forward carefully from there.

Comment: You're right! I feel like an idiot now... Thank you so much, I was looking for errors in the code below line 71 as that is what Brackets highlighted as wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @skepticalmind Technically, brackets is correct, as newlines are valid in attribute values, and in your first example line you open an `img` tag (that happens to have a newline in its `style` attribute), then try and close with an `h1` tag (the "<h1..." itself was taken to be part of the `style` attribute's value), and that mismatched *closing* tag is where the error is encountered. It doesn't parse attribute values themselves for validity and afaik it can't be configured to warn on (valid) newlines in attributes, so complaining about line 71 is pretty much the best it can do for you.